# Centering the text inside the input type tag

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to center the value of the text inside the Input type tag.

Here's the code.

```
    #input{
    text-align: center;
}

<input type=\"text\" class=\"input\" value=\"Welcome Back&nbsp;". $_SESSION['username']."&nbsp;!\">
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP?

Comment: Can you show us your css?

Comment: i use echo bro its a php. as of now i dont have a css.

Comment: Just use `text-align: center;`.

Comment: Bro, your question has nothing to do with PHP !!

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/3w46x/)

```
text-align: center;
```

It ll do all the magic you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type=\"text\" value=\"Welcome Back&nbsp;". $_SESSION['username']."&nbsp;!\" style=\"text-align: center;\">
```

I have added style

Comment: @AlexAlejandro   Thanks,

If you wish, you can mark this as answer.. :-)

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, accept it as being the answer to your question.

Comment: the problem is because of css defination that use id `#input` but uses as class `class='input'`, this will not take effect untill chang `#input` to `.input` or add an id attribute to input `<input id='input' ... `

Answer (score 1):

your class defination is `#input` that isn't true, you should do define it with dot

```
.input{
    text-align: center;
}

<input type=\"text\" class=\"input\" value=\"Welcome Back&nbsp;". $_SESSION['username']."&nbsp;!\">
```